# What is an Efficient way of searching for files in storage in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a music player app in android. In the MainActivity I'm listing all the (.mp3,.wav,.flac) files in a simple listview. I'm using this `getSongs` method to search for such files:

```
public void getSongs(File root) {
    File listFile[] = root.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory() && !listFile[i].isHidden()) {
                getSongs(listFile[i]);

            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".mp3") || 
                    listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".MP3") || 
                    listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".flac")|| 
                    listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".wav")) {
                    songList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then from the main activity I'm calling this:

```
File externalSD = new File("/storage/"); //gets the external but not internal!!
getSongs(externalSD);
File internalSD = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()); //gets the internal but not external!!
getSongs(internalSD);
```

Works well for me (I have only 100 songs) but in case you have a large number of such files it is really slow (my friend has around 2.5k songs..).
I would like to know how I can achieve this more efficienty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

- Using an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to retrieve the songs in another thread.
- Getting the song list from Android's media database instead - you will have to work with SQL and [MediaStore.Audio](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html). Remember to use an AsyncTask or a [Loader](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

The second option would be faster since you don't have to traverse the whole system.